# How to show row values as column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table from which I want to show row values as column values.

As per my knowledge PIVOT function is used for it.

Original table structure as follows https://ibb.co/MVdsD01

and the desired table should be like https://ibb.co/Vt704WF

So from above two images, you can find out that category, color and percentage columns values want to show as row values as per lines.

Comment: Please don't post images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need pivot, just use `CASE`

```
SELECT line,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'UT' THEN duration END) AS ut_min,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'UT' THEN percentage END) AS ut_percentage,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'UT' THEN color END) AS ut_color,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'AOOT' THEN duration END) AS aoot_min,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'AOOT' THEN percentage END) AS aoot_percentage,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'AOOT' THEN color END) AS aoot_color
    --, the rest of your columns...
FROM table_name
GROUP BY line
ORDER BY line;
```

Comment: Thanks Pham X. Bach for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go with conditional aggregation like below

```
select
    ut_color=           MAX(case when category='UT'     then color else NULL end),
    aoot_color=         MAX(case when category='AOOT'   then color else NULL end),
    od_color=           MAX(case when category='OD'     then color else NULL end),
    fd_color=           MAX(case when category='FD'     then color else NULL end),
    td_color=           MAX(case when category='TD'     then color else NULL end),
    sl_color=           MAX(case when category='SL'     then color else NULL end),
    ql_color=           MAX(case when category='QL'     then color else NULL end),
    nrt_color=          MAX(case when category='NRT'    then color else NULL end),
    ut_min=             MAX(case when category='UT'     then duration else NULL end),
    aoot_min=           MAX(case when category='AOOT'   then duration else NULL end),
    od_min=             MAX(case when category='OD'     then duration else NULL end),
    fd_min=             MAX(case when category='FD'     then duration else NULL end),
    td_min=             MAX(case when category='TD'     then duration else NULL end),
    sl_min=             MAX(case when category='SL'     then duration else NULL end),
    ql_min=             MAX(case when category='QL'     then duration else NULL end),
    nrt_min=            MAX(case when category='NRT'    then duration else NULL end),
    ut_percentage=      MAX(case when category='UT'     then percentage else NULL end),
    aoot_percentage=    MAX(case when category='AOOT'   then percentage else NULL end),
    od_percentage=      MAX(case when category='OD'     then percentage else NULL end),
    fd_percentage=      MAX(case when category='FD'     then percentage else NULL end),
    td_percentage=      MAX(case when category='TD'     then percentage else NULL end),
    sl_percentage=      MAX(case when category='SL'     then percentage else NULL end),
    ql_percentage=      MAX(case when category='QL'     then percentage else NULL end),
    nrt_percentage=     MAX(case when category='NRT'    then percentage else NULL end)
from yourtable 
group by category
```